# Upgrading Zend Framework from version X to version Y

Tags: php, zend-framework

Whenever I upgrade Zend Framework I study the changelogs ( http://framework.zend.com/changelog ) but still feel like I am going through a bit of leap of faith to ensure my application does not break.

So far, I have not really had any problems. A large amount of the application is under unit test and web test. But, tests do not have 100% coverage so the whole process of upgrading ZF is still a bit unnerving.

## So the Question is...

**Where would I be able to find definitive information on interface changes and 'backwards compatibility breaks' when upgrading from 'ZF version X' to 'ZF version Y'?**

---

Also if anyone has any general upgrade tips on upgrading vendor code smoothly then that would be of interest.

i.e.

- Do you write a set of unit tests to work on all framework components used by your app?

---

Also any specific tips on upgrading from ZF 1.8 to 1.11 would be welcomed in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZF's has a [strict release policy](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/Release+Policies+and+Conventions)

1. A major release may contain any changes, including bug fixes, backwards compatible features and functionality enhancements, and backwards incompatible releases.
2. A minor release may only contain backwards compatible changes, including bug fixes and backwards compatible features and functionality enhancements.
3. A mini release may only contain bug fixes. Note that no new features, functionality enhancements, or API changes are allowed whatsoever. The framework should look and behave the same across mini releases.

The release notes usually contain information about changes that are not backwards compatible. And as you can see, those may only happen between major releases, which is from ZF1 to ZF2, but not from ZF1.8 to ZF1.11.

Now, just because the may not happen, doesnt mean they dont happen, but from my experience all changes were backwards compatible. I remember they changed the autoloader and static Filter invocation in some previous version. ZF would continue to work as usual, but raise deprecation notices. So you are encouraged to take action then, but it won't break your application if you don't.

Basically, as long as your application is Unit-Tested, you should not have any (or very little) problems updating. Update, run your test, if something breaks, fix. Push the updated release to your development and see if it has any notices or warnings.

If you really, really want to know all the changes, then do an SVN Diff between your old version and the version you want to update to.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was a bit unnerved when I found that the interface to Zend_Validate_StringLength changes between 1.9 and 1.10 
So I guess that is a rare special case.
see: http://www.eatmybusiness.com/food/2010/04/17/gotcha-zend_validate_stringlength-interface-changes-between-versions-19-and-110/153/

Comment: @JW that's one example of a backwards compatible change. If you do not pass in an array, the constructor will fetch the passed arguments and use them like it was the old method signature. See the [source code for `__construct`](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Validate/StringLength.php)

Comment: oh yes...I see the func_get_args...  thanks for that. Aaaaa, I feel more relaxed already :o)